# Downloading the xcode documentation failed

Tags: xcode

I am trying to install the Documentation of iOS 5.1 Library. 
[image]
But the worst thing is that after completion of entire download (not at the start of download) it is giving me the following error message.

[image]

How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but....

follow this two steps:

```
$ cd /Users/youruser/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
$ sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

I guess it will work.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but actually it was my mistake that the destination folder was deleted. So failures were in downloading. But thanks for the reply